# Why does lineTo() change interior pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This situation is difficult to explain, so let me illustrate with a picture:
[image: pixel lightening]

Those pixels inside the first shape created are lightened. The screen is cleared with black, the red and green boxes are drawn, then the path is drawn. The only fix that I've found so far was setting the line width of the boxes to 2 pixels, for the reasons outlined [here](http://corlan.org/2012/01/12/canvas-quirks/).

Here's the code being used to draw the squares:

```
sctx.save();
sctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
sctx.lineWidth = this.width;
sctx.beginPath();
sctx.moveTo(this.points[0].x, this.points[0].y);
for (var i = 1; i < this.points.length; i++)
{
    sctx.lineTo(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y);
}
sctx.closePath();
sctx.stroke();
sctx.restore();
```

And the lines:

```
sctx.save();
sctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
sctx.lineWidth = 5;
console.log(sctx);
sctx.beginPath();
sctx.moveTo(this.points[0].x, this.points[0].y);
for (var i = 1; i < this.points.length; i++)
{
    sctx.lineTo(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y);
}
sctx.closePath();
sctx.stroke();
sctx.restore();
```

And a picture of the same situation where the boxes are drawn at 2px width:
[image: Second awkwardness]

Is `lineTo()` perhaps messing with the alpha values? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, the same thing occurs when `sctx.closePath();` is omitted from the path being drawn.

Comment: Any chance you can toss up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Possibly, if I really have to. I'm using a rather sizable library(of my own creation): https://github.com/Bloodyaugust/SugarLab, so I'd have to cut down a lot of that for it to be helpful at all.

Comment: I'd say your analysis is correct, the boxes are being drawn at reduced opacity and drawing the shape above it is resetting those boxes "inside" the shape to full opacity. I'm afraid I don't know enough about the technologies involved to speculate why.

Comment: What you have indicates that you know the problem, but I would have to see more of it in action to know for sure. Reducing the problem to the bare minimum repeatable result would help get to the root of the question.

Comment: The solution is not to put 2px wide lines, but to use `fillRect()` instead of `lineTo()` — If you post s fiddle, I will put the correct answer.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as though this is a currently undocumented rendering bug that for some reason appears on all platforms. There is very little info out there about it, and it will hopefully be attended to before HTML5 is the official standard.

As a workaround, don't use `lineTo()`'s, use multiple sets of single lines.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have: http://jsfiddle.net/g3Kvw/
As you can see it seems to be 2px wide. But if you change that to use fillRect() instead of lineTo(), you have http://jsfiddle.net/g3Kvw/1/ which is looking good.

Problem: you will not be able to draw something that is not a rectangle with this method.

But, if you sum 0.5 to EVERY int coordinate (x,y): http://jsfiddle.net/g3Kvw/3/ you will get the regular line.

I think this is some kind of antialiasing calculation bug on FF & webkit... But I didn't find it in the bug tracker, and this "weird" solution to convert the number to float, in order to get a solid line is quite confusing. Because using integers should be enough.

Comment: While this does indeed serve to solve the anti-aliasing, it doesn't explain the issue with lineTo() changing pixels inside of its area. In fact, even when the lines inside of the lineTo() are the correct color by changing their width to 2, they overlap the orange line by a small amount.

Comment: @Bloodyaugust that is because of rendering engines. Are you setting the width and height of the canvas in BOTH CSS and JS sides?

Comment: The only time I touch width and height are in the HTML declaration: `<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1000" height="600" style="position: relative"></canvas>`

Comment: Can you try adding canvas.width = 1000; and canvas.height = 600; where canvas is your canvas object at JS.?

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle of your things?